# why is this tag not centering vertically?

Tags: css, html

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pMZ5T/

HTML:

```
<div id="arrowcont">
    <img width="30px" height="30px" src="check.jpg" style="float:left;" />
    <div id="verticalcenter">Full Guide</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

CSS:

```css
#arrowcont {
    height: 40px;
    width: 275px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical - align: middle;
    background - position: 0 50 % ;
}

#verticalcenter {
    vertical - align: middle;
    background - position: 0 50 % ;
}​
```

i want to vertically center both of these so that it looks better when they are next to each other. the image is actually a check mark next to it.

i know this question has been asked a lot and i actually even asked it in the past, but i used the method in the other question i had but i still can't center this vertically. does anyone see where i went wrong? i was trying the background-position tag and the vertical middle tag, but neither worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/GyVSt/

What I did:

1. Changed `#arrowcont` to `display: table-cell` (will allow `vertical-align`)
2. Removed `float: left` from `img`
3. Added `display: inline-block` for `img` and `#verticalcenter` (will put `img` and `#verticalcenter` next to each other)

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align: middle` can be applied only to table-cell elements, you can use `display: table-cell` but in this can break your layout.

Comment: what is a safe way to do this then?

Comment: it is also safe if you use right css styles, by "breaking your layout" I meant that it can break your current layout which is done assuming that `div` elements have `display: block`

Comment: but if you don't want to use table-cell style, you can use javascript to calculate and set the position manually depending on elements' heights, but that's not a good solution IMO

Comment: i changed it: http://jsfiddle.net/pMZ5T/3/ , but only the image seems to be centered, the text still looks a little too high

Comment: that will be fixed if you specify `line-height`, browser doesn't know the exact line-height so it can't be centered